# Responsive - Social Media Icons not aligning Horizontally (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, social-media

I have inserted my social media div in the header.php file and have coded it with css to position.

```
#header_icons {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -6%;
    margin-left:85%;

    }
```

Problem is that when it responds, the Social Media Icons fall vertical opposed to sitting Horizontally alongside each other.

Website: www.aym.ie

This is the result in Responsive mode http://take.ms/qMHJ2

Question: How do I code the Social Icons to sit Horizontal when viewed in responsive mode?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom CSS add

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {

    #header_icons {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left:0;
    }

}
```

You might need to play with the media break-point and the margin values, but hopefully this will get you started.

Good luck!